# When ToUpper is used for entry text entering is getting late

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

For login screen in user id entry field if entered small characters also making it uppercase by using ToUpper() and displaying. Making ToUpper() taking time to display text in user id field.

Is there any solution to make entered text to uppercase instead of ToUpper() in specific field

Comment: this is incomprehensible.  Please post the relevant code demonstrating what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

To enforce the `uppercase` input field without using `ToUpper()`

You can achieve this by setting the `InputType` of the `EditText` to `TextCapCharacters`.
This property will automatically capitalize all characters entered in the field.

```
// Set InputType to automatically capitalize characters
editText.InputType = InputTypes.TextFlagCapCharacters;
```

Comment: This question is for Xamarin Forms...

Comment: You can use OnEntryTextChanged method for Xamarin Forms

Comment: Instead of giving more than one answer for the question, please combine your answers into one answer in accordance with xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnEntryTextChanged method for Xamarin Forms

```
public YourPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Attach the TextChanged event handler to the Entry control
            yourEntry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        }

        private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Convert the entered text to uppercase and update the Entry's Text property
            yourEntry.Text = e.NewTextValue?.ToUpper();
        }
```